# How do I access the preorder content?

Tags: far-cry-3

I have preordered Far cry 3 on steam but I can't seem to find where the extra missions are. Anyone know how to get access to the extra missions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you bring up your map, you should see two black and orange circles, one is seen in the bottom left of the minimap at the start of this video - http://www.gameanyone.com/video/512416 - (don't watch too much of it, as that's one of the missions!)

Comment: I don't see them, the only orange circle was from that extra mission you can buy with 10 uPlay points or something

Comment: They're outside the starting area's map, try scrolling a bit to the right

Comment: @JohnoBoy I finished the whole game, unlocked every map and tower and I still can't see it

Comment: I'd try re-downloading the DLC then...